# One class SVM always returns FALSE

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm, anomaly-detection, one-class-classification

I have a project in my ML course about anomaly/novelty detection and decided to study the One-class SVM algorithm as described in this paper: http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/69731/tr-99-87.pdf. In the package `e1071` in R there is an `svm` function that seems to support one-class classification. However, when I try to use it the predictor always returns false (even on the training set, which is the weirdest thing). Here is my code :

```r
library(e1071) # for svm classifier
library(IMIFA) # for USPS dataset
library(caret) # for confusion matrices

data(USPSdigits)

digits.train <- USPSdigits$train
digits.train <- digits.train[order(digits.train$V1), ]
digits.train$is.zero[digits.train$V1 == 0] <- "TRUE"
digits.train$is.zero[digits.train$V1 != 0] <- "FALSE"
digits.test <- USPSdigits$test
digits.test <- digits.test[order(digits.test$V1), ]
digits.test$is.zero[digits.test$V1 == 0] <- "TRUE"
digits.test$is.zero[digits.test$V1 != 0] <- "FALSE"

digits.train.features <- digits.train[digits.train$V1 == 0, -c(1, 258)]
digits.train.labels <- digits.train[digits.train$V1 == 0, 258]
digits.train.nu <- 0.5
digits.train.bandwith <- 0.5*256
digits.train.model <- svm(x = digits.train.features, type = 'one-classification', kernel = 'radial', nu = digits.train.nu, gamma = digits.train.bandwith)
digits.train.fitted <- predict(digits.train.model, digits.train.features)
digits.train.confusionMatrix <- table(Predicted = digits.train.fitted, Reference = digits.train.labels)
print(digits.train.confusionMatrix)

digits.test.features <- subset(digits.test, select = -c(is.zero, V1))
digits.test.labels <- digits.test$is.zero
digits.test.fitted <- predict(digits.train.model, digits.test.features)
digits.test.confusionMatrix <- table(Predicted = digits.test.fitted, Reference = digits.test.labels)
print(digits.test.confusionMatrix)
```

and my output is :

```
> print(digits.train.confusionMatrix)
         Reference
Predicted TRUE
    FALSE 1194
> print(digits.test.confusionMatrix)
         Reference
Predicted FALSE TRUE
    FALSE  1648  359
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27375517/one-class-classification-with-svm-in-r) help you?

Comment: I have already seen this post and my code is inspired by it, but on this more complicated dataset it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

I created a working example. Adjust naming conventions to your own. I have used a very expressive naming convention to show exactly what I did.

Training on only 1 number results in a lot of columns with the same values. These return as errors in `svm` and should be removed. The function `nearZeroVar` from caret is an ideal function for this. If you ever use the recipes package, it is called `step_nzv`.

```
library(e1071)
# library(caret) # caret used for nearZeroVar function.

# data steps like OP's
digits.train <- USPSdigits$train
digits.test <- USPSdigits$test

digits.train$is.zero[digits.train$V1 == 0] <- "TRUE"
digits.train$is.zero[digits.train$V1 != 0] <- "FALSE"


digits.test$is.zero[digits.test$V1 == 0] <- "TRUE"
digits.test$is.zero[digits.test$V1 != 0] <- "FALSE"


train_the_positives <- subset(digits.train, is.zero == "TRUE")

# get the columns with 99% of the same values
cols_to_remove <- caret::nearZeroVar(train_the_positives, freqCut = 99/1)

svm.model <- svm(train_the_positives[, -cols_to_remove],
                 type = 'one-classification',
                 nu = 0.10,
                 kernel = "radial")

# predictions on train_the_positives set
svm_predictions_on_train_the_positives <- predict(svm.model, train_the_positives[, -cols_to_remove])
table(Predicted = svm_predictions_on_train_the_positives,
      Reference = train_the_positives$is.zero)

         Reference
Predicted TRUE
    FALSE  121
    TRUE  1073

# predictions on full train set
svm_prediction_on_full_train_set <- predict(svm.model, digits.train[, -cols_to_remove])
table(Predicted = svm_prediction_on_full_train_set,
      Reference = digits.train$is.zero)

         Reference
Predicted FALSE TRUE
    FALSE  6069  121
    TRUE     28 1073


# predictions on test set
svm_prediction_on_test_set <- predict(svm.model, digits.test[, -cols_to_remove])
table(Predicted = svm_prediction_on_test_set,
      Reference = digits.test$is.zero)

         Reference
Predicted FALSE TRUE
    FALSE  1638   68
    TRUE     10  291
```

Comment: My god, it works as wonder !! Thank you very much !! Do you have an idea where the error could come from though? Rather from a mathematical aspect or rather a computation aspect?

Comment: @tudoroancea, I noticed when I ran your svm, it generated an error in the calculations when running, but still created a model. Problably due to some stationary variables. 
Also, please accept the answer as that will mark the question as closed.